# PayPal: How to recieve an email when users send payments to my PayPal developer account ? (Using React.js )

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, mern

I've integrated PayPal buttons in my website using react.js, and I want to get an email every time a user pays using that PayPal button on my website, How can I implement that?

P.S: I'm using PayPal sandbox

I want to do the following:

```js
    
useEffect(() => {

    window.paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: (data, actions, err) => {
            return actions.order.create({
                intent: "CAPTURE",
                purchase_units: [
                    {
                        amount: { currency_code: "CAD", value: 50 },
                    },],
            });
        }, onApprove: async (data, actions) => {

            setPaid(true);
            setCompleted(true);
            // *THEN SEND ME AN EMAIL THAT A PAYMENT HAS BEEN DONE*


        },
        onError: (err) => {
            setCompleted(true);
            console.log(err);
        },
    })
        .render(paypal.current)

}, []);
```

Comment: I don't see how this is related to frontend or React. If it's possible, it's a backend topic.

Answer (score 0):

The actual email should be sent from a backend.

Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your backend, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you can store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller (which will be react in your case).

For the frontend approval flow, instead of your own `useEffect` implementation in your question, consider the official [@paypal/react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js). Give it createOrder and onApprove function parameters that call your backend (likely using `fetch`).  For examples of such functions, see the full stack example in the integration guide or the one at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server (currently this latter one is the best as it shows how to handle 3 different cases for the capture response)